# Trying to access 'title' attribute via getEntryTableAttributeHtml. Any idea how?

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to get access to the attribute title using this, but does not work. If I switch out 'title' for slug, uri, etc. It works. But not title. Anyway I can do this?

```
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{    
    switch ($attribute) {
        case 'title':
            return $entry->title . ': Something appended to title';
            break;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Added in `return $entry->title . ': Something appended to title';` to the case to show I want to append something to the title.

I want to be able to just append some text, icon, or html to the titles in the entries list in the CP.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna change the title one way is override the `__toString()` method on your model.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return (string)$this->name;
}
```

If you wanna chage the status icon next to the title you can override the `getElementQueryStatusCondition` function on your ElementType class

```
public function getElementQueryStatusCondition(DbCommand $query, $status)
{}
```

Regards

Comment: I don't follow the __toString() part. I updated my code a tiny bit. I want to be able to just append some text, icon, or html to the titles in the entries list in the CP.